# How to use variables in Gatling duration specifications?

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm looking for a way to set the duration of a scenario using a variable. I need to be able to use different numbers here when starting the test from the command line.

I can pass a value from command line to my configuration, it works fine. What I can't figure out is how to describe this part: `during (10 minutes)` using a variable instead of the magic number `10`. As far as I can tell, two imports are related to this part of the code: `scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt` and `scala.language.postfixOps`.

So here is a sample of my code:

```scala
val usersPerSec: Double = 5
val pingScenario: ScenarioBuilder = {
    scenario("Ping")
      .exec(http("Ping").get(myUrl).check(status.is(200)))
}

setUp(
    pingScenario.inject(
      constantUsersPerSec(usersPerSec) during (10 minutes)
    ).protocols(myHttpProtocol)
```

And this is what I'd like to have:

```scala
val usersPerSec: Double = 5
val duration = 10
val pingScenario: ScenarioBuilder = {
    scenario("Ping")
      .exec(http("Ping").get(myUrl).check(status.is(200)))
}

setUp(
    pingScenario.inject(
      constantUsersPerSec(usersPerSec) during (duration minutes)
    ).protocols(myHttpProtocol)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, [during()](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/bda6c0bc545cc4375a589b4b46c00e3dc13b6d84/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/controller/inject/open/OpenInjectionSupport.scala#L41) takes a `FiniteDuration` as opposed to an `Int`

```
  case class ConstantRateBuilder(rate: Double) {
    def during(d: FiniteDuration) = ConstantRateOpenInjection(rate, d)
  }
```

Therefore, you can do something like:

```
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  val usersPerSec: Double = 5
  val duration = FiniteDuration(10, MINUTES)
  val pingScenario: ScenarioBuilder = {
    scenario("Ping")
      .exec(http("Ping").get("test").check(status.is(200)))
  }

  setUp(
    pingScenario.inject(
      constantUsersPerSec(usersPerSec) during (duration)
    ).protocols(myHttpProtocol)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I tried again simply with integers though and it works. I must have made a mistake earlier.